# Change product cross sells h2 heading "You may be interested in..." on WooCommerce cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart, hook-woocommerce

There is a WooCommerce Hook called **woocommerce_cart_collaterals** that displays a text in a div that I would like to change.

This is the short form of the unmodified HTML output:

```
<div class="cart-collaterals">
    <div class="cross-sells">
        <h2>You might be interested in...</h2>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to change the text inside the h2. I have added an action for this hook but the given argument variable is just empty, I don't know what to do to get access to the h2.

This is what I've tried by adding to the theme's functions.php:

```php
function action_woocommerce_cart_collaterals( $woocommerce_cart_totals) { 
    print_r($woocommerce_cart_totals);
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'action_woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 10, 1);
```

What to do I need to modify to edit the text output in the h2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `woocommerce_cart_collaterals` action hook callback function, contains no arguments. Use the `woocommerce_product_cross_sells_products_heading` filter hook instead

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_product_cross_sells_products_heading( $string ) {
    // New text
    $string = __( 'My new text', 'woocommerce' );

    return $string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_cross_sells_products_heading', 'filter_woocommerce_product_cross_sells_products_heading', 10, 1 );
```